# What happens if I assign a character to an int type in Java?

Tags: java

In this piece of code:

```
public class TestChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = 'A';
        int n = c; 
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Why does it print 65? Is it the Unicode value of the character 'A'?

Answer (score 2):

'A' is the character literal A (Unicode code value 65)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Unicode value of ' A'

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints `65` instead of `A` is [*overloading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html): the method `println` is actually a number of different methods, distinguished by the arguments they take. There are these two among others:

[println(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char)) - prints the value as a character

[println(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) - prints the value as a number

Internally the representation of the char 'A' and the int 65 is the same. The only difference is that the two types have different storage sizes. However, when you pass them to `println` the type is used to select which variant of the method to call.